# run executable on google compute engine from code

Tags: c#, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to write some C# code to create a VM in Google Compute Engine and upload and run a different, computationally heavy bit of code on it. Is this possible? I can find plenty of support for creating instances but nowhere says how I might accomplish the second part. Any help or advice would be great.
Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean the second part? can you be more specific on what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: the second part as in uploading and running the executable

Answer (score 0):

You can store your second executable to Google Cloud Storage and when you create the second VM, set the [startup script](https://developers.google.com/compute/docs/howtos/startupscript) to:

- download the binary from Google Cloud Storage, and
- execute it with some parameters

Answer (score 0):

I've ended up downloading the executable to my instance and installing mono to run it and saving that as an image and then using startup scripts to execute.

Thanks all!

Comment: Great to hear that you’ve solved your issue! Can you please [accept your own answer](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/01/accept-your-own-answers/) so that this question is marked as closed? Thanks!